# Проблема с переносом скрипта из HTML в JS файл?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка

У меня возникла проблема переноса скрипта в script.js. Кнопку по событию вызываю появляются вопросы, но дальше не могу понять что писать что бы переключались вопросы. Я только учусь JS. Может кто подскажет.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf8'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sergey-oganesyan.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/stylepromer.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Тест</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Тестирование</h1>
<style type="text/css"> 
.wrapper{
width: 600px;
height: 130px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: none;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

var countQuest = 0;
var plus = 0;
var test_start = 0;

function check(num){

if(num == 4){ 

document.getElementById('area').style.display='block'; 

document.getElementById('end').style.display='inline';

if(test_start == 0){

//Массив вопросов
var questions = ["Hello","Дом","Дерево","Homeland"];

//Массивы вариантов ответов
var number1 = ["Как дела","House","House"]; 
var number2 = ["Привет","Cat","Door"];  
var number3 = ["Пока","Dog","Wall"];  
var number4 = ["Дом","Tree","Tree"];

document.getElementById('question').innerHTML=questions[countQuest];

document.getElementById('option1').innerHTML=number1[countQuest];
document.getElementById('option2').innerHTML=number2[countQuest];
document.getElementById('option3').innerHTML=number3[countQuest];
document.getElementById('option4').innerHTML=number4[countQuest];

//Массив правильных ответов
var answer = [1,0,3,1];

test_start = 1; 
}
}
else{
//Массив вопросов
var questions = ["Hello","Дом","Дерево","Homeland"];

//Массивы вариантов ответов
var number1 = ["Как дела","rterter","House","Природа"]; 
var number2 = ["Привет","Cat","Door","Родина"]; 
var number3 = ["Пока","Dog","Wall","Остров"]; 
var number4 = ["Дом","Tree","Tree","Планета"];  

//Массив правильных ответов
var answer = [1,0,3,1];

if(num == answer[countQuest]) plus++;

if(questions.length - 1> countQuest){

countQuest++;

document.getElementById('question').innerHTML=questions[countQuest];

document.getElementById('option1').innerHTML=number1[countQuest];
document.getElementById('option2').innerHTML=number2[countQuest];
document.getElementById('option3').innerHTML=number3[countQuest];
document.getElementById('option4').innerHTML=number4[countQuest];

}
else{ 

document.getElementById('area').style.display='none';
alert('У Вас ' + plus + ' правильных ответа!');
}
}
}

</script>

<div style="margin-top: 200px;">

<div id="area" class="wrapper">

<center>      

<p style="font-size: 38px;font-weight: bold;padding-top: 2px;color: #000;" id="question"></p>

<button class="myButton" id="option1"></button>

<button class="myButton" id="option2"></button>

<button class="myButton" id="option3"></button>

<button class="myButton" id="option4"></button>

</center>

</div>

</div>  

<br><center>
<button id="start" class="myButton">Приступить к тесту</button>

<script type="text/javascript"> var curent_url = document.URL; document.write("<a id='end' style='display: none;' class='myButton'></a>"); </script>   
</center>
<script src="libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Разберитесь с `innerHTML` будьте с ним аккуратны, он затирает предыдущую информацию. [Почитайте тут.](https://learn.javascript.ru/basic-dom-node-properties#innerhtml-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: И еще просмотрите внимательно структуру своего документа. У вас все на кучу. То скрипт, то HTML, то опять скрипт..., так не далают... Все скрипты лучше в конец или в `<head>` (те, которым там место)

Comment: Так я и хочу все в один файл вынести, но у меня не получается